# How to use logback filter by this case?

Tags: java, logback

I have three java files:

- Asimple.java
- Bsimple.java
- Csimple.java

Asimple.java:

```
private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("i am logger");
```

Bsimple.java:

```
private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("smile");
```

Csimple.java:

```
private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("i am handsome");
```

I want to print logger name "i am*". (just print Asimple.java and Csimple.java)
Not "smile". How to change logback.xml?

Comment: Please use codeblocks (four spaces at the start of the line) to format your code. Then there should be no need to rely on `<br>` all of the time, and it makes the code much more readable. Also, always tag your questions with the language they are about, java in this case. Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to change logback config. You need to change how you get Loggers. Try `LoggerFactory.getLogger(Asimple.class);` in Asimple.java for example.